# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2, connection, windows-server-2008-r2

Does anyone know how to fix:

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure

I am running a Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 and getting this error message when I am running a batch script. The account I am running it on has enough permissions. So I am not quite sure why I am getting this message.

The batch script connects to a local SQL server, gets all "tag" information taken from the last 10 minutes and writes it to a CSV file, then sends it away to another process.

I got a similar script that does the same thing, but gets all the "tag" information taken from the last 3 minutes. This one runs without problems. So I am wondering if perhaps the job is a bit too much?

Comment: Are there any related error messages in the SQL Server error log?

Comment: Hi Dan! When I run the batch file, it seems the SQL server crashes. When I check the SQL logs, it says the server is starting up again. Hmm

Comment: I thought something like that might be the case. Make sure you have the latest service pack installed. Be aware that SQL Server 2008 is out of mainstream support so I don't expect a bug fix will be forthcoming, although you might be able to workaround the problem depending on what the script is doing.

Comment: It was actually SQL Server 2008 R2, I'll try to update the Service Pack to 3 and see if that helps. Just need to book a time to restart the server since it is a production server.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is also out of mainstream support too. Hopefully, SP3 will resolve the problem.

Comment: Did not help. I will try to rewrite the command in powershell.